# Editing storyboard files on the iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uistoryboard

I've got an idea I would like to share.
I am an iOS-developer, and I love Storyboards in iOS5. They are a great and easy way to prototype some functionality.

Would it be possible to develop an app or web-app that made editing storyboards possible?
As far as I have seen, they are just XML.

Linked to cloud services like Dropbox, this would be a great tool for quickly prototyping ideas, or update exciting projects.

What do you guys think?
Are there anything that makes this impossible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't develop for iPad on iPad. Apple won't let you, because they don't allow arbitrary code execution. A front end to generate XML qualifies.

On the other hand, something for sketching out storyboard on the device and then emailing auto-generated XML, which the iPad couldn't execute, may be possible.

It sounds kind of pointless though. If you're sketching, use a whiteboard, and if you're programming, use a Mac. Or share the actual storyboard file or the entire project by dropbox. Or a github repo.

Comment: It's not entirely hopeless.  I've got the skeleton of a .XIB XML editor project going and it works quite well.

Comment: I'm not talking about compiling or generating code. Just storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a prototyping app to test out your sketch ideas . Dapp for iPhone is free and there is Mockup & CodeGen. These are a couple ways I sketch out my ideas and the mockups you made can be transferred to code so its easy to import. I'm not sure if this is a good answer but from what I read this is something you are looking for. Or Moleskin has a Storyboard notebook for comics which you could very well use too.These are just ways I sketch out my apps.